# python program that records number of attempts made during a random number between 1-10

Tags: python, random, numbers

trying to create a Python program to guess a number between 1 to 9 entered by the user and count the number of attempts taken by the computer to guess the correct number.

this is what I have so far, need to add on a counter that tells me how many attempts have been made, any advice?
thank you

```
import random #Python import random module in Python defines a series of functions for generating or manipulating random integers
target_num, guess_num = random.randint(1, 10), 0
while target_num != guess_num:
    guess_num = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 10 until you get it right : '))
print('Well guessed!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize a `counter` and increment it at each attempt.

`counter += 1` is a shorcut for `counter = counter + 1`.

The `print()` function use a [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#input-and-output) to print the `counter` variable.

```py
import random #Python import random module in Python defines a series of functions for generating or manipulating random integers
target_num, guess_num, counter = random.randint(1, 10), 0, 0
while target_num != guess_num:
    counter += 1
    guess_num = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 10 until you get it right : '))
print(f'Well guessed! {counter} attempts.')
```

Answer (score 0):

### Code correction

You need to check `Target num` and user num usung `If` inside the `while` loop as follows.

```
import random 
target_num, guess_num = random.randint(1, 10), 0
attempts =0
while 1: 
    guess_num = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 10 until you get it right : '))

    if guess_num == target_num:
        print('Well guessed!')
        print(f"You took {attempts} chances")
        
        break

    else:
        print(f"you gussed {guess_num} which is wrong")
        attempts = attempts + 1
        pass
```

Sample outputs#

```
Guess a number between 1 and 10 until you get it right : 3
you gussed 3 which is wrong.
Guess a number between 1 and 10 until you get it right : 3
you gussed 3 which is wrong.
Guess a number between 1 and 10 until you get it right : 10
Well guessed!
You took 2 chances
```